# How do I set variables in bat file and pass them to php variables?

Tags: windows, php, batch

I am working on a script in Windows to get system information , I want to store the result of each command in a bat variable, then pass them to php variables.

Here the script that I tried:

```
for /f  "tokens=1 delims=[" %a in ('ver') do SET OS=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=|" %a in ('wmic os get Name') do SET version=%a
for /f  "tokens=2 delims=[" %a in ('ver') do SET kernel= %a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture') do SET arq=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %a in ('wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors') do SET numero_cpu=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %a in ('wmic cpu get manufacturer') do SET fabricante_cpu=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=" %a in ('wmic cpu get Name') do SET nombre_cpu=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed') do SET frequence_cpu=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic bios get name') do SET name_bios=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic bios get version') do SET version_bios=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber') do SET serial_bios=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic bios get manufacturer') do SET fabricant_bios=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic NIC get Description') do SET red=%a 
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic SOUNDDEV get productname') do SET audio=%a
for /f  "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description') do SET video= %a

ECHO %OS%:%version%:%kernel%:%arq%:%numero_cpu%:%fabricante_cpu%:%nombre_cpu%:%frequence_cpu%:%name_bios%:%version_bios%:%serial_bios%:%fabricant_bios%:%red%audio%:%video%:
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`. This causes problem parsing `wmic` output with `for /F` loop: even *seemingly empty* line contains that leading `0x0D` (*carriage return*) and therefore the first token is identified there.

**Proof** (note escaped `^,` comma):

```
==>for /F "delims=" %g in ('wmic os get caption^, name /value') do @echo 1st="%g"
"st="
"st="
"st="Caption=Microsoft Windows 8.1
"st="Name=Microsoft Windows 8.1|C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk1\Partition2
"st="
"st="
"st="

==>
```

Solvable using an additional (nested) loop as used in the `:getwmic` subroutine (a subroutine approach chosen to limit multiple coding). The `for` loop parameters are

- `%%g` to retrieve the `name=value` lines only (see `/value` switch and `findstr`);
- `%%G` to retrieve the desired value (2nd token `%%H`) *and* to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned.

Supply two line parameters to the `:getwmic` procedure (referenced `%1` and `%2` there):

- a simple `wmic` query (enclosed in a pair of double quotes) querying the only property of a `wmi` class, e.g. `"wmic os get Name"`;
- an environment variable *name* the queried property should be assigned to, e.g. `version`.

Next script gives some examples only; all `set` commands are merely `echo`ed for debugging purposes; remove all `echo` no sooner than debugged. Note that

- `OS` variable already exists; hence consider another name (`OSx`);
- use `set "variable=value"` syntax with double quotes to escape some characters of a special meaning in batch scripting, e.g. `|`, `&`, `<`, `>` etc., and ensure there are no (accidentally forgotten) trailing white spaces;
- `|` pipe is escaped with `^` in `for /f ...  /value ^|findstr "="')`.

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[" %%a in ('ver') do echo SET "OSx=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ver') do echo SET "kernel=%%a%"

call :getwmic  "wmic os get Name" version
for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%a in ("%version%") do echo SET "version=%%a%

call :getwmic "wmic os get osarchitecture" arq
call :getwmic "wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors" numero_cpu
call :getwmic "wmic cpu get manufacturer" fabricante_cpu
call :getwmic "wmic cpu get Name" nombre_cpu
call :getwmic "wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description" video

goto :yoursequel

:getwmic
for /F "delims=" %%g in ('%~1 /value ^|findstr "="') do (
  for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ("%%g") do echo set "%~2=%%H"
)
exit /B

:yoursequel
ECHO %OS%:%version%:%kernel%:%arq%:%numero_cpu%:%fabricante_cpu%:%nombre_cpu%:%frequence_cpu%:%name_bios%:%version_bios%:%serial_bios%:%fabricant_bios%:%red%audio%:%video%:
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~g`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`|` pipe, `&`, `<` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: I'll take a look of that, I'll read it with calm ! Thanks for your answer!